# next js with Turborepo ui package import through error: You may need an appropriate loader

Tags: reactjs, next.js, progressive-web-apps, turborepo

I'm working with next.js 13.1.1
and first time configuring a monoRepo-based project using [turborepo](https://turbo.build/repo/docs). and I want to use

- @next/bundle-analyzer
- @sentry/nextjs
- @next-pwa

without the above config everything works perfectly

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  poweredByHeader: false,
  compress: true,
  transpilePackages: ['ui']
}
module.exports = nextConfig
```

but if I use below code

```
module.exports = withNextPwa(withBundleAnalyzer(
  withSentryConfig({
    nextConfig,
    sentryWebpackPluginOptions,
  })
));
```

getting error

```
../../packages/ui/components/Button.tsx
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:28)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
import { ButtonProps } from "../type";
| 
> export const Button = (props:ButtonProps) => {
|   return <button>{props.label}</button>
| }

Import trace for requested module:
../../packages/ui/components/Button.tsx
../../packages/ui/index.tsx
./src/components/home/hero.tsx
./src/components/home/index.tsx
```

I have already spent more than one day to solve this but no-luck. any suggestion or guidance is welcome thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why, but when I add transpilePackages even empty, it works:

```
...
transpilePackages: []
...
```

Some bug?